# How to pass comma in SASS variable?

Tags: css, sass

I have a `SASS` variable, `$active-color: #a16117`

Now I want to use that in a `RGBA` value so I created to `RGB` value of that variable like so, `$active-color-rgb: 161,97,23,` and I tried to use it like this, 
`border: 2px solid rgba($active-color-rgb 0.8)` but `SASS` throws this error

```
error 2-basics/buttons.sass (Line 10: wrong number of arguments (1 for 4) for `rgba')
```

I believe it's failing on the commas. Any ideas on how to remedy this?

Comment: Why not just use 3 variables for your R,G and B? Otherwise you need to do string interpolation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SASS you can use HEX for the color, no need to translate to RGB.

```
$active-color: #a16117;
border: 2px solid rgba($active-color, .8);
```

If you indeed want to translate to RGB though, then just do:

```
$active-color-rgb: rgb(161,97,23);
border: 2px solid rgba($active-color-rgb, .8);
```

---

JsFiddle Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/yvnoueb3/1/

You van view more details on the SASS docs:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#rgba-instance_method

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
// Declare the color as RGB; SASS will treat this as hex
$red: rgb(255,0,0);
// Declare an alpha
$alpha: .5;
// Declare another color variable as a color with an alpha
$redAlpha: rgba($red, $alpha);
```